# Maximum number of writable data containers

Tags: c++-amp

**OS:** Windows 8.1 64 Bit - fully updated

**IDE:** Visual Studio Professional 2013 - Version 12.0.30110.00 Update 1 - fully updated

I have a situation, where I get the following exception not during compile-, but run-time.

**The number of writable data containers referenced in the entry function of the parallel_for_each call (17) exceeds the selected accelerator's limit (8).**

The function where this happens looks like the following

```
void run_epoch(
    accelerator_view mainAccelView,
    ActivatorState activatorState,
    TrainingState trainingState,
    array_view<double, 2> avLayer1,
    array_view<double, 2> avLayer2,
    array_view<double, 2> avLayer3,
    array_view<const double, 2> avPredictors,
    array_view<const double, 2> avTargets,
    array_view<double> avErrors,
    int epoch
    ){
    accelerator_view mainAccelView = accelerator::accelerator().create_view(queuing_mode::queuing_mode_immediate);

    int noOfColumnsPredictors = AmpUtils::get_no_of_columns(avPredictors);
    int noOfRowsPredictors = AmpUtils::get_no_of_rows(avPredictors, noOfColumnsPredictors);

    int noOfColumnsLayer1 = AmpUtils::get_no_of_columns(avLayer1);
    int noOfColumnsLayer2 = AmpUtils::get_no_of_columns(avLayer2);
    int noOfColumnsLayer3 = AmpUtils::get_no_of_columns(avLayer3);

    int noOfRowsLayer1 = AmpUtils::get_no_of_rows(avLayer1, noOfColumnsLayer1);
    int noOfRowsLayer2 = AmpUtils::get_no_of_rows(avLayer2, noOfColumnsLayer2);
    int noOfRowsLayer3 = AmpUtils::get_no_of_rows(avLayer3, noOfColumnsLayer3);

    array_view<double, 2> avOutputLayer1(noOfRowsPredictors, noOfRowsLayer1);
    array_view<double, 2> avOutputLayer2(noOfRowsPredictors, noOfRowsLayer2);
    array_view<double, 2> avOutputLayer3(noOfRowsPredictors, noOfRowsLayer3);

    array_view<double, 2> avErrorsLayer1(noOfRowsPredictors, noOfRowsLayer1);
    array_view<double, 2> avErrorsLayer2(noOfRowsPredictors, noOfRowsLayer2);
    array_view<double, 2> avErrorsLayer3(noOfRowsPredictors, noOfRowsLayer3);

    array_view<double, 2> avThresholdLayer1(noOfRowsPredictors, noOfRowsLayer1);
    array_view<double, 2> avThresholdLayer2(noOfRowsPredictors, noOfRowsLayer2);
    array_view<double, 2> avThresholdLayer3(noOfRowsPredictors, noOfRowsLayer3);

    array_view<double, 3> avWeightsLayer1(noOfRowsPredictors, noOfRowsLayer1, (noOfColumnsLayer1 - 1));
    array_view<double, 3> avWeightsLayer2(noOfRowsPredictors, noOfRowsLayer2, (noOfColumnsLayer2 - 1));
    array_view<double, 3> avWeightsLayer3(noOfRowsPredictors, noOfRowsLayer3, (noOfColumnsLayer3 - 1));

    array_view<double, 2> avErrorsTempBuffer(noOfRowsPredictors, noOfRowsLayer3);
    int errorTempBufferSize = avErrorsTempBuffer.extent.size();

    array_view<double> avEpochErrors(noOfRowsPredictors);

    try{
        parallel_for_each(extent<1>(AmpUtils::get_no_of_rows(avPredictors)), [=](index<1> idx) restrict(cpu, amp){
            int predictorRow = idx[0];

            // step 1: compute
            // step 11: compute layer 1
            compute_layer(activatorState, avPredictors[predictorRow], avLayer1, avOutputLayer1, noOfColumnsLayer1, predictorRow);

            // step 12: compute layer 2
            compute_layer(activatorState, avPredictors[predictorRow], avLayer2, avOutputLayer2, noOfColumnsLayer2, predictorRow);

            // step 13: compute layer 3
            compute_layer(activatorState, avPredictors[predictorRow], avLayer3, avOutputLayer3, noOfColumnsLayer3, predictorRow);


            // step 2: calculate_error
            // step 21: calculate_error layer 3
            for (int column = 0; column < noOfRowsLayer3; column++){
                double neuronError = avTargets[predictorRow][column] - avOutputLayer3[predictorRow][column];
                avErrorsTempBuffer[predictorRow][column] = neuronError * neuronError;
                avErrorsLayer3[predictorRow][column] = neuronError * AmpActivator::derivative2(activatorState, avOutputLayer3[predictorRow][column]);
            }

            double errorSum = 0.0;
            for (int column = 0; column < errorTempBufferSize; column++){
                errorSum += avErrorsTempBuffer[predictorRow][column];
            }

            avEpochErrors[predictorRow] = errorSum;

            // step 22: calculate_error layer 2
            calculate_error_layer(activatorState, avErrorsLayer2[predictorRow], avErrorsLayer3, avLayer3, avOutputLayer2[predictorRow], noOfRowsLayer3, noOfRowsLayer3);

            // step 23: calculate_error layer 1
            calculate_error_layer(activatorState, avErrorsLayer1[predictorRow], avErrorsLayer2, avLayer2, avOutputLayer1[predictorRow], noOfRowsLayer2, noOfRowsLayer2);


            // step 3: calculate_updates
            // step 31: calculate_updates layer 1
            calculate_updates_layer(trainingState, avErrorsLayer1[predictorRow], avPredictors[predictorRow], avThresholdLayer1[predictorRow], avWeightsLayer1[predictorRow], (noOfColumnsLayer1 - 1), noOfRowsLayer1);

            // step 31: calculate_updates layer 2
            calculate_updates_layer(trainingState, avErrorsLayer2[predictorRow], avPredictors[predictorRow], avThresholdLayer2[predictorRow], avWeightsLayer2[predictorRow], (noOfColumnsLayer2 - 1), noOfRowsLayer2);

            // step 31: calculate_updates layer 3
            calculate_updates_layer(trainingState, avErrorsLayer3[predictorRow], avPredictors[predictorRow], avThresholdLayer3[predictorRow], avWeightsLayer3[predictorRow], (noOfColumnsLayer3 - 1), noOfRowsLayer3);


            // step 4: update_network
            // step 41: update_network layer 1
            update_layer(avLayer1, avWeightsLayer1[predictorRow], avThresholdLayer1[predictorRow], noOfColumnsLayer1, noOfRowsLayer1);

            // step 42: update_network layer 2
            update_layer(avLayer2, avWeightsLayer2[predictorRow], avThresholdLayer2[predictorRow], noOfColumnsLayer2, noOfRowsLayer2);

            // step 43: update_network layer 3
            update_layer(avLayer3, avWeightsLayer3[predictorRow], avThresholdLayer3[predictorRow], noOfColumnsLayer3, noOfRowsLayer3);
        });

        avEpochErrors.synchronize();

        double epochErrorsSum = 0.0;
        for (int i = 0; i < (int)avEpochErrors.extent.size(); i++){
            epochErrorsSum += avEpochErrors[i];
        }

        avErrors[epoch] = epochErrorsSum;
    }
    catch (std::exception e){
        std::wcout << "Exception Project::run_epoch: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

According to this MSDN-post [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5f7d1094-54fa-4e56-a0f5-e4f41aa08f48/got-concurrencyruntimeexception-please-help?forum=parallelcppnative) and also [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nativeconcurrency/archive/2012/04/16/data-under-the-covers-in-c-amp.aspx), the maximum number of writeable containers should have been increased to 64 since Windows 8.

My question is now, are there different types of writeable containers whereas I still only might use a maximum of 8 of a certain type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strictly speaking the limitation is on the number of UAVs. This is coupled to the DX version not Windows.

> Limited number of writable array_view/array/texture/writeonly_texture_view objects allowed per kernel
>   C++ AMP supports a limited number of writable array_view/array/texture/writeonly_texture_view objects per kernel. Specifically, the total number of writable array_view + array + texture + writeonly_texture_view per kernel should not exceed 8 on DirectX 11 and 64 on DirectX11.1. The total number of allowed read-only array_view/array/texture objects per kernel is 128 and specifying the read-only restriction can help you avoid hitting the limit on maximum number of allowed writable array_view/array/texture/writeonly_texture_view objects per kernel.

From [Parallel Programming in Native Code](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nativeconcurrency/archive/2012/09/27/read-only-array-view-array-in-c-amp-part-2-of-2.aspx).

DX11.1 is supported on Win8 and has been back ported in some limited form to Win7. Looking at my machine it is running Windows 8.1 but seems to be using DX 11 not 11.1 drivers. `DXDIAG.EXE` will tell you what you are using. You need to make sure that your card supports DX11.1 and that you have the latest drivers installed.

Comment: Thanks again for your help! My system is completely updated and using even NVIDIA's beta drivers. However, the quite new graphics card GTX 770 doesn't support DirectX 11.1. So I'm stuck here on a hardware problem :(

Comment: Note that you can also query DX version at runtime by inspecting `accelerator::version`. The value is hexadecimal hi/loword so `b0000` is 11.0, `b0001` is 11.1, etc.